"Unrecognized response content type" in Acquia Migration Accelerate
I am trying to run the Acquia Migrate Accelerate tool on a production D7 database. I've got as far as migrating Public Files and each time it stops after about 2000 out of 7000 entries. I also get the same message when trying other migrations e.g. Webform submissions, again it fails part way through.
There are HTTP errors in the console log:
http://hse.local/acquia-migrate-accelerate/api/migration/process/27
GET
500
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

LogicException: There is no active operation. in Drupal\acquia_migrate\Batch\MigrationBatchManager->isMigrationBatchOngoing() (line 654 of modules/contrib/acquia_migrate/src/Batch/MigrationBatchManager.php).
Drupal\acquia_migrate\Controller\HttpApi->migrationProcess()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 121)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

I've successfully run this process on a UAT site with has the same structure but much less data (5000 items to migrate rather than 70000), so I'm wondering if it's struggling with the volume of data
Does anyone have any experience of this particular error, or of how well AMA performs with larger migrations in general?

